# Detecting patterns in a graph network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching

If we create a random graph

```
Chop[LowerTriangularize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}], -1], 0.6] /.0 -> \[Infinity] // MatrixForm
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[%]
```

[image]

How can we detect repeating patterns in larger graphs?

Particularly, patterns including a negative or positive parameter:

```
SetProperty[%, 
 EdgeStyle -> {x_ :> (PropertyValue[{%, x}, 
       EdgeWeight] /. {a_?Positive -> 
        Directive[Thickness[Abs@a/400000] , Opacity[.5], Green], 
       b_?Negative -> 
        Directive[Thickness[Abs@b/400000] , Opacity[.5], Red]})}]
```

[image]

The only thing that comes to mind is using the graph as an image and trying some pattern detection that way

Edit:

I'd like to find Patterns of an arbitrary amount of nodes, for example n = 3 nodes, such as:

[image]

and how many times it occurs in a large network such as:

[image]

Hopefully to see if there is any frequent structures

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "pattern". Can you expand the question and explain it?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thanks @Szabolcs , I've updated the post to hopefully explain better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd like to find Patterns of an arbitrary amount of nodes, for example n = 3 nodes, such as:
>
> [image]

These are called networks motifs. The usual reference is [Milo et al, Network Motifs: Simple Building Blocks of Complex Networks](http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/doi/10.1126/science.298.5594.824).

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/) has functionality for counting motifs.

Example:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", 
    "MetabolicNetworkArabidopsisThaliana"}];
```

Count 3-motifs in `g`:

```
motifs = AssociationThread[
   IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}],
   IGMotifs[g, 3]
   ];
```

Also count in a random graph with the same vertex and edge counts, and compare:

```
rg = RandomGraph[{VertexCount[g], EdgeCount[g]}, 
  DirectedEdges -> True]

rmotifs = AssociationThread[
   IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}],
   IGMotifs[rg, 3]
   ];
```

(Note: if you are serious about this, you would want to use `IGRewire` on the original graph to create a randomized version with the same degrees. I just took a shortcut here.)

How many more times does each motif appear in the empirical network than the random one?

```
BarChart[
 Quiet@N[motifs/rmotifs],
 ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 LabelingSize -> 29, ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 1/2
 ]
```

[image]

---

If you also want to take the colour into account, there is no special functionality in IGraph/M yet (but could be implemented based on the underlying igraph library).

You can use `IGVF2FindSubisomorphisms`, which supports coloured graphs, to find edge-coloured patterns. Note that `IGVF2FindSubisomorphisms` looks for all subgraphs, not merely induced ones. You would have to filter induced ones yourself. `IGLADFindSubisomorphisms` can filter induced subgraphs efficiently, but it does not support edge colours (only vertex colours).

Please see the documentation for more information on all these functions.

Comment: Thanks! I get an error creating `rmotifs` , `rg` appears not to be defined. Could this be because I am not using mma12?

Comment: Also struggling to find the 11.0 version for `Labellingsize`

Comment: I'm struggling a little trying to implement `IGVF2FindSubisomorphisms[]`. It has parameters `subgraph` and `graph`. Do I test a predefined subgraph ~ motif on a large graph. Maybe I'm not navigating the documentation well, it seems a little thin. I get a result, if I use a random n=3 graph, of numbers. If you've any advice? (Thanks so much for all your help)