# IGraphM error creating a list of motifs using IGMotifs[]

Tags: graphs-and-networks, igraphm

A follow up from a previous question
[Detecting patterns in a graph network](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244592/detecting-patterns-in-a-graph-network)

Thanks to @Szabolcs

```
motifs = AssociationThread[IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}], 
   IGMotifs[g, 3]];
```

Unfortunately, when I try on a graph `g` , created from a whole matrix not just `LowerTriangularize[]`, although the data is mirrored ({2,1} has the same value as {1,2}) I get the following error:

[image]

Why is `IGMotifs[]` creating such a short list?

Does a `LowerTriangularize[]` skew my results when mirrored? I imagine they will be the same but with two directional arrows - is this important in detecting abnormal occurrence?

Comment: your graph is undirected (sorry, must be terse, wrist injury...)

Comment: @Szabolcs Perfect! Thanks, feel better! Cherry juice helped me with a joint injury - for fullness, adding `DirectedEdges -> True` to the `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[]` works